# How to write special characters to a file

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I want to write some special characters from UTF-16 to a file. I tried some methods but I don't get what is going on behind scenes. Below code writes 'u' character to file. How can I write special charaters from UTF-16?

```
    File f = new File("test");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-16");
    fos.write(16757);
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why you are lingering with code? I really don't get what is your aim. My question was How can I write special characters from UTF-16?

Comment: Your code is supposed to demonstrate what you are trying to do. The code you've posted doesn't do that. It's not clear what you are trying to do. What is a special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use `write()` of `OutputStreamWriter` to write the encoded chars:

**Change:**

```
fos.write(16757);
```

**To:**

```
osw.write(16757);
```

Comment: Using  OutputStreamWriter.write(int) the result is identical to  FileOutputStream.write(int). Additionally the write(int) method only writes one byte but UTF-16 requires two bytes per character.

Comment: by accepting this answer I assume the original question was the UTF-16 BOM which is written automatically by the OutputStreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

try maybe something like this:

```
    File f = new File("test");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write("16757").getBytes("UTF-16"));
```